# What is the potential energy of the spring?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy, spring

[image: Diagram]

What is the potential energy of the spring?

On the left side there is a gravitational force $mg$ acts on the spring, same on for the right side. So, If force $mg$ streches the spring $x$ units then $2mg$ will strech the spring $2x$. Therefore,

$$F=kx$$

$$2mg=kx$$

$$\frac{2mg}{k}=x$$

$$U=\frac{1}{2}k{x}^{2}=\frac{1}{2}k(\frac{2mg}{k})^{2}$$

$$U=\frac{2{m}^{2}{g}^{2}}{k}$$

Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the left end of the spring was tied with a string to an immovable object, the force on the spring would be $mg$.  Since the spring would be in static equilibrium, it is obvious that due to Newton's 3rd law, the string would have to supply a force of $mg$ towards the left.

Your drawing shows exactly the same setup regarding the forces involved, with the weight on the left supplying a force of $mg$ towards the left.  Thus, the force stretching your spring is actually $mg$, not $2mg$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I can't understand why it is. Can you explain it with a simpler language please?

Comment: Are you familiar with Newton's 3rd law?

Comment: Yeah, I know the third law of Newton. When one body exerts a force on a second body, the second body simultaneously exerts a force equal in magnitude and opposite in direction on the first body.

Comment: If your spring was tied on the left end to a wall, and the mass was hanging off the right pulley, how much force would be exerted on the spring?

Comment: If we consider the hanging mass is $m$, then the force would be $mg$.

Comment: How much force is being provided by the wall, and what is the direction of that force?

Comment: Hmm. I never thought it. I don't know the answer, I can guess but I can't explain why.

Comment: Last comment before I take this to chat: if you can use Newton's 3rd law to answer my question, my posting above will make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104104/discussion-between-iccqbe-and-david-white).